# How to replace a tag in yaml file with auto-indent contents in new line

Tags: python, yaml

I wonder whether this can be done or not:

So I have a .yaml file with the following pattern

```
- xxx: xxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxx:
  - xxxxxxxxx: xxxx
    http_config: %httpProxy%
```

I want to replace `%httpProxy%` with some string displayed in a well-indented new line:

```
- xxx: xxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxx:
  - xxxxxxxxx: xxxx
    http_config:
      proxy_url: http://proxy:8080
```

I can use `.replace("%httpProxy%", "\n\r      proxy_url: http://proxy:8080")`, but I don't want to hard-code the number of spaces (6 in this case) before `proxy_url`, as the number of space before `http_config` may not necessarily be 4.

Are there any better ideas?

Comment: You need a YAML parser. It'll take care of the indentation for you.

Comment: @MattDMo I use yaml parser to load it after the replacement, `yaml.load(output_str, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)`, but if the indentation is wrong, the parser will fail

Comment: You need to parse it *before* you make the change outlined in your question. Once parsed, you should be able to search for `http_config` keys and if their value equals your match string, create a new daughter key with the proxy info.

Comment: with this tag `%httpProxy%`, the yaml file cannot be parsed

Comment: So how did it get in there if it's invalid YAML?

Comment: It is a template used in a pipeline, with the tags to be replaced with different settings by a script. After the replacement, it will become a valid YAML

Comment: Hi @MattDMo, seems this question is closed, can you re-open it again?

Comment: If it's a template, use a templating engine. Jinja for example has [an indent filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) to help you with proper indentation.

Comment: @KenTsoi I reopened it. Please add all the relevant information from the comments to your question so it is clearer.